# How to Use @ResponseBody data to populate a table

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I Have a function in the controller of the MVC Project like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public GetOrdersByEmailRequest createRequest(@RequestParam String email1) {

    GetOrdersByEmailRequest getOrdersByEmailRequest = null;
    try {
        // LOG.info("Preparing Request for lookup Email :" + lookoupEmail);
        getOrdersByEmailRequest = new GetOrdersByEmailRequest();
        getOrdersByEmailRequest.setEmail(email1);
        getOrdersByEmailRequest.setFetchType(OrderDetailsFetchType.FETCH_WITH_SUBORDER_DETAILS);
        // getOrdersByEmailRequest.setPageSize(GETORDERSBYEMAIL_PAGESIZE);
        // getOrdersByEmailRequest.setRequestProtocol(Protocol.PROTOCOL_JSON);
        // getOrdersByEmailRequest.setResponseProtocol(Protocol.PROTOCOL_JSON);
        // getOrdersByEmailRequest.setStart(PAGESIZE_OFFSET);
        getOrdersByEmailRequest.setUserTrackingId(null);
        getOrdersByEmailRequest.setContextSRO(null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // LOG.error("Error in preparing OMS Request",e);
    }
    return getOrdersByEmailRequest;

}
```

So now when i use the submit button on the webpage the browser displays the jSON object . Now instead of displaying the object i want to use it and populate a table in the JSP File . How should i go about doing this .?

Comment: See the [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/sewm6/)

Comment: Since you are returning a JSON object, you have to render that with JS code.

Comment: Use ajax post. You will get the JSON object as response of that ajax post call. Then iterate through the data and render html dom and append it to a table.